# Emotion css props are not getting the theme object when running tests with vitest

Tags: css, reactjs, vite, emotion, vitest

*Context: I am migrating a project over from CRA to the Vite ecosystem and I am having some issues with the tests. I did not have this problem when these tests were run with Jest in the CRA environment.*

The project I am working on makes use of emotion's [css prop](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop). It is a common occurrence to be passing down the theme to the css interpolation function, like so, for example:

```
//styles.ts
export const componentStyles = (theme: Theme) => {
  console.log(theme);

  return css`
    font-size: ${theme.typography.fontSizes['24']};
    color: ${theme.utils.getColor('lightGrey', 500)};
  `;
};
```

```
//Component.tsx
import { componentStyles } from './styles.ts';

export default function SomeComponent() {
  return (
    <div css={componentStyles}>
      Hello
    </div>
  );
}
```

During runtime the above prints the theme object correctly. The problem starts when I try to run tests  using `vitest`, where `theme` comes in as `{}`

My `vite.config.ts` is the following:

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />

import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import { ViteEjsPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-ejs';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), 'VITE_');

  return {
    define: {
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode),
    },
    plugins: [
      react({
        babel: {
          plugins: ['@emotion/babel-plugin'],
        },
      }),
      tsconfigPaths(),
      svgr(),
      ViteEjsPlugin(),
    ],
    build: {
      outDir: 'build',
    },
    test: {
      globals: true,
      environment: 'happy-dom',
      setupFiles: './src/setupTests.ts',
    },
  };
});
```

I cannot understand why there is this disparity between actually running the code and running the code for the tests. Isn't vitest taking into account any configuration you have made for vite, so as to keep parity? At least that is my understanding from [the docs](https://vitest.dev/config/#configuration)

Any pointers to the right direction are fine, thanks

Comment: Did you wrapped your component with theme provider in test? https://emotion.sh/docs/theming

Comment: Yep, I have done so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently when migrating a legacy monolith from jest to vitest. I found the issue was that the context of the theme got lost when it came to styled components.

I already had a `withTheme` wrapper for my tests which worked for `jest` but not for `vitest`

A temporary workaround was to add an additional `themeProvider` only for my tests. Below is an example of how I passed both the MUI themeProvider and the `@emotion/react` theme provider.

This fixed the theme object in my tests.

Hopefully this offers a temporary solution

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { ThemeProvider as EmotionThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react'
import getTheme from './theme';

const withTheme = (Component) => {
  const theme = getTheme('light');

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <EmotionThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          {Component}
      </EmotionThemeProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
export default withTheme;
```

Comment: God damn! Much better than my own solution, which was to do `useTheme` in every component that used the `css` prop and explicitly pass the `theme`argument to the css interpolation function, like so: `css={wrapperStyle(theme)}`, just for the tests to work. I would not have thought to do what you did there. We are not using materialUI, we have our own in-house style library, but this works as far as I could tell from testing some components! Will migrate the code to use your solution (remove explit `theme` passing) and will accept your answer if that works for everything!

Comment: Also, for me, this seems to work even if I swap places between EmotionThemeProvider and ThemeProvider

Comment: I think I am gonna cry :D, everything worked. You cannot imagine for how long we had this issue, and it was the reason we had not initially migrated over to vite+vitest since a long time ago. The solution I had ended up with did the trick, but I had to change actual code just for the tests to work and I did not like that one bit. Your solution is so clean, nice!

Comment: For the record, because I think someone can misunderstand, the difference with my testing setup was that I was not using the emotion theme provider on top of our library's theme provider; I was only using our own theme provider